# TThread.Synchronize causing (near) deadlock in Delphi 2009 (worked in Delphi 7)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2009

In Delphi 2009, synchronize'd functions that worked fine in Delphi 7 execute with sublime slowness until you wiggle the mouse over the open form.  Wiggling the mouse causes the program to go into some mouse idle state which does `CheckSynchronize()`.  `CheckSynchronize()` appears to be called less frequently in Delphi 2009 than in Delphi 7, but we can't figure out why or where.

Placing this code:

```
    procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender : TObject)
       Classes.WakeMainThread := WakeMainThread;
    end;

    procedure TMyForm.WakeMainThread(Sender: TObject);
    begin 
      SendMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
    end;
```

Speeds things along at the normal rate. But I get: `EAccessViolation in module rtl120.bpl` when the thread dies if it's used in a modal app (works fine for a simple dialog utility).  I'm guessing 'Classes.WakeMainThread()' is being called just as much as it is in Delphi 7, but sending WM_NULL to application.handle isn't accomplishing anything.  I guess it's time to 'get steppin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TApplication.Create is getting called from another DLL, hence it is waking an invalid handle or some nonsense in that callback.

You need to eliminate statically linked DLLs that include [vcl.]controls.pas because TApplication.Create happens in some initialization code in that unit.

Once you do this, synchronize will be restored to it's former glory.

Unfortunately, fixes you make in one version of Delphi might be undone by changes made in another version of Delphi.  So if the problem comes back, go back to the drawing board. Step through the initialization code, specifically the `initUnits` procedure in system.pas.  It runs the initialization code and will bump into vcl.controls.pas eventually and you can peer into the `UnitInfo` record to find out which file this is being called from.

---

The best way to fix this is to use the `delayed` with all your external dlls (at least all your Delphi VCL external DLLs).

```
 function didntknowIusedcontrolsbutIdo() : Integer; external 'useful.dll' delayed;
```

But this only works in Delphi 2010 and up. Good thing you upgraded to XE2 between the time you asked this question and the time you finally find a satisfying answer to it.

Answer (score 6):

The internals of the `Synchronize()` mechanism have not changed much between D7 and D2009.  Sure, there have been new features added (asynchronous queuing, anonymous methods, etc), but the core implementation to run code in the main thread has not changed.  What is more likely happening is something else in your main thread code that you have not shown yet is blocking the main thread from processing pending messages and `Synchronize()` requests correctly.

Comment: Does my edit help answer the question?  We've been digging into where the CheckSynchronize function is called and it's only when wm_null is passed to the active form, somehow there's a disconnect between passing it to the application and the form that is running the thread.  This is what seems to have changed, probably something with the way MDI child forms are owned and notified by the MDI window, but I have no idea where to start looking for that in the VCL (or how to rectify it).

Comment: `CheckSynchronize()` is also called when `TThread.WaitFor()` is called in the context of the main thread, and whenever the main thread message loop goes idle after processing all of the pending messages in the queue.

Comment: Hey, I think you may have [answered this already](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=243719) a few years ago, sorry for dredging it up.  But, is this the same problem? (for the record, they're sharing the RTL bpl)