# Prevent Delphi MDI application from creating TApplication in external DLL

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-xe2, vcl

**This is the question (the rest is just so you can tell me I'm doing it all wrong)**.

Is there any way I can ensure that the first binary file to be ran (i.e. my executable) is the first one to initialize vcl.controls.pas?

---

I asked [this question a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742954/tthread-synchronize-causing-near-deadlock-in-delphi-2009-worked-in-delphi-7) and I figured out how to fix it there and synchronize was working again just swell for Delphi 2009.

Now we've got Delphi XE2 and the same symptom is happening.  TThread.Synchronize locks up until the system idles or you move the mouse over the active form causing the program to go super slow.  I could recreate the problem in Delphi 2009 because I got lucky and found the source to be an non-circuitously linked DLL, but I don't believe this to be the case with XE2.  I don't know why XE2 decides to initialize code differently than Delphi 7 or 2009, but according to my answer on the other question, nothing really changed with TThread, so it must be somewhere else.

Well, I've been stepping through the initializations of my main MDI app and it appears to call TApplication.Create (which happens in the initialization of VCL.Controls.pas) inside a linked DLL.  I can't say that I understand why this is a problem since I build everything with the same runtime packages (VCL, RTL, etc...).

Comment: It would seem to me that that DLL isn't using runtime packages... When you use runtime packages there should only be one reference to the VCL across all of them.

Comment: Unless there's some hidden .dproj weirdness I can confirm that every DLL is using the exact save runtime packages, including VCL. I actually did fix this problem by turning the offending DLL's `external` calls into delphi functions that call `loadlibrary` and `getprocaddress`.

Answer (score 2):

We have been experiencing the same issues you described (although in C++ Builder). There seem to be three possible solutions.

1) Remove all the VCL dependencies from your DLLs.  This is where my company is ultimately going, but it probably isn't very helpful advice short-term.

2) Use packages instead of DLLs.  This is the official answer we got from Borland support (long-ago).  Apparently, if you create a package (BPL) instead of a DLL, it can do a better job figuring out the VCL initialization.

3) I don't know what hidden problems are lurking with this third solution because it's quite a hack, but here is how I am currently applying a band-aid to our system until we can get the VCL out of our DLLs (and it *seems* to work).

```
WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    delete Application;
    Application = new TApplication(NULL);
```

But I have to confess that it makes me more than a little nervous (and it makes me feel kind of dirty).

The idea, as I'm sure you can translate it into Pascal, is to destroy the original TApplication object that was created by the DLL and that was assigned to the `Application` global variable.  Then create your own `TApplication` object in the executable's `WinMain` and assign it to the global `Application` variable.  As long as nothing has stored a pointer to the original TApplication object before you get the opportunity to throw it away, it seems like it should be okay.

Comment: We wound up fixing it by setting all the externally referenced VCL enabled DLLs to ['delayed'](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinC1.htm) which basically turned them all into dynamically linked DLLs but that 3rd option of yours is very, very interesting and very, very scary.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said in the comments, I think I understand what is going on here... If you use `external` for your entry points into the DLL from the main exe, they are loaded by the OS on program startup. This would complicate things a great deal since the BPLs are loaded by the runtime (using `LoadLibrary()`) well after that point.

So, your DLL is loading the runtime BPLs separately to the EXE before the EXE has had time to do it's initialisation.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what is happening, what I want to know is if there is any way to rectify that.  It seems strange that the compiler is incapable of construing things in a way that initializes units and DLLs in a predefined manner.  The most annoying part about this is that it worked fine in Delphi 7.  Then I had to debug and fix it in Delphi 2009. Then, with exactly the same code, I had to debug and fix it in Delphi XE2.