# Method called on thread using Synchronize does not return without moving the mouse

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

I have a unit and form which uses a worker thread to query a database. After each query is executed a method is called using Synchronize to update the UI.

It seems that whenever a call to the methods using `Synchronize()` is made, the process stops until I shake the mouse or interact with the keyboard.

Below is the basics of what I am doing. This example is complete other than that I did not provide a database connection or queries for a real database- I am hoping it will be enough to see the code.

A theory is that limiting the synchronize calls to one call at the end to update the entire UI will make this work, though I am not 100% on if or why this would help - something to do with not switching what the CPU is doing too often perhaps? It does not seem possible to have only one Synchronize given how I must iterate through different query results to populate the TListViews. I do want to keep using list views as shown and not change the method for displaying rows of data.

```
  unit ExampleCode;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls, ADODB;

type
  TRefreshThread = class(TThread)
  public
  Procedure Execute; override;
  procedure UpdateLabel1;
  procedure UpdateLabel2;
  procedure UpdateLabel3;
  procedure UpdateLabel4;
  procedure populateListView1;
  procedure populatelistView2;
  procedure populatelistview3;
  procedure OnThreadTerminate(Sender : Tobject);
  constructor Create;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    ListView1: TListView;
    ListView2: TListView;
    ListView3: TListView;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  var
  Form1: TForm1;
  RefreshThread : TRefreshThread;
  Query : TADOQuery;
  someDatabase : TADOConnection;

  implementation

   {$R *.dfm}

procedure TRefreshThread.UpdateLabel1;
begin

Form1.Label1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field1').AsString;

end;

procedure TRefreshThread.UpdateLabel2;
begin

Form1.Label1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field2').AsString;

end;


constructor TRefreshThread.Create;
begin

FreeOnTerminate := true;
OnTerminate := OnThreadTerminate;
inherited Create(false);

end;

procedure TRefreshThread.OnThreadTerminate(sender : TObject);
begin

sender := nil;

end;

procedure TRefreshThread.UpdateLabel3;
begin

Form1.Label1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field3').AsString;

end;

procedure TRefreshThread.UpdateLabel4;
begin

Form1.Label1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field4').AsString;

end;


procedure TRefreshThread.populateListView1;
var
Item1 : TListItem;
begin

Item1 := Form1.ListView2.Items.Add;
Item1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field5').AsString;
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field6').AsString);
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field7').AsString);

end;


procedure TRefreshThread.populateListView2;
var
Item1 : TListItem;
begin

Item1 := Form1.ListView2.Items.Add;
Item1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field8').AsString;
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field9').AsString);
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field10').AsString);


end;


procedure TRefreshThread.populateListView3;
var
Item1 : TListItem;
begin

Item1 := Form1.ListView2.Items.Add;
Item1.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Field11').AsString;
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field12').AsString);
Item1.SubItems.Add(Query.FieldByName('Field13').AsString);

end;


procedure TRefreshThread.Execute;

begin


Query.Create(nil);

Query.Connection := SomeDatabase;

Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD1 from TABLE');

Query.Active := true;

Synchronize(UpdateLabel1);

Query.Close;
Query.SQL.Clear;

Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD2 from TABLE');

Query.Active := true;

Synchronize(UpdateLabel2);

Query.Close;
Query.SQL.Clear;


Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD3 from TABLE');

Query.Active := true;

Synchronize(UpdateLabel3);

Query.Close;
Query.SQL.Clear;

Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD4 from TABLE');

Query.Active := true;

Synchronize(UpdateLabel4);

Query.Close;
   Query.SQL.Clear;


   Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD5, Field6, Field7 from TABLE');

   Query.Active := true;

   try
   while not Query.Eof do
   begin
       Synchronize(PopulateListView1);
       Query.Next;
   end;
   finally
   Query.Close;
   Query.SQL.Clear;
   end;


   Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD8, Field9, Field10 from TABLE');

   Query.Active := true;


   try
   while not Query.Eof do
   begin
   Synchronize(PopulateListView2);
   Query.Next;
   end;
   finally
   Query.Close;
   Query.SQL.Clear;
   end;


Query.SQL.Add('select FIELD11, Field12, Field13 from TABLE');

Query.Active := true;


try
  while not Query.Eof do
begin
Synchronize(PopulateListView3);
Query.Next;
end;
finally
Query.Close;
Query.SQL.Clear;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

Timer1.Create(nil);
Timer1.Interval := 1000;
RefreshThread := TRefreshThread.Create();

end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

if RefreshThread = nil then
RefreshThread := RefreshThread.Create();

end;

end.
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: The code above is all that is being done other than the specifics of the UI and the database operations. The synchronized call to DoUIStuff is not returning until the mouse is moved.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I will see about getting some code which can run on its own though it could be the complexity/amount of UI operations I am doing that makes the difference.

Comment: Please see updated post with code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Synchronize()` puts the method pointer into a queue and then waits for the main UI thread to process that queue.  That processing happens inside of the RTL's `CheckSynchronize()` function.

As I stated in comments to [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742954/):

> `CheckSynchronize()` is also called when `TThread.WaitFor()` is called in the context of the main thread, and **whenever the main thread message loop goes idle after processing all of the pending messages in the message queue**.

Normally, `Synchronize()` "wakes up" the main UI thread, in case there are no pending messages.  There is a function pointer in the RTL named `WakeMainThread`, which `Synchronize()` calls if assigned.  This lets the main UI thread post a message to itself so it can call `CheckSynchronize()` sooner rather than later.

The behavior you describe can occur under one of these possible scenarios:

1. your thread code is in a console app that does not have a `TApplication` object, which hooks into `WakeMainThread`, or the app does not have a message loop that processes the wake-up message.
2. your code is in a GUI app, and something in the main UI thread is blocking it from processing messages in a timely manner.
3. there are no pending messages in the main message queue when `Synchronize()` is called, and for whatever reason no function has been assigned to `WakeMainThread`, so the main UI thread does not receive `Synchronize()`'s wake-up request, and thus does not process the synchronize queue until a new message is received eventually, like mouse/keyboard activity.

You have not provided any details about your application or its setup, so there is no way to diagnose which of these possibilities is actually affecting your project.

Comment: The application is a form which is parented to a panel in a larger application. The form handles all the details of threading and updates to its UI and, besides the specific UI and database access details, works as described in the post. Nothing I know of in the main UI thread would be blocking. Is there a way to check the main message queue? What about WakeMainThread?

Comment: I replaced the first thread with a timer which spawns the secondary thread in the OnTimer event. This seems to cause a wake up request to be received eventually but very slowly. Is there a good way to manually trigger a wake up request so it happens as soon as the method called with synchronize is finished?

Comment: In your example code, your refresh thread is spending almost all of its time syncing with the main thread, and spending very little time in the actual worker thread. You are creating new refresh threads even if earlier threads may still be running. You are over-burdening the main thread with sync requests, it is going to fall behind. This is a misuse of threads. If you are going to spend that much time in the main thread, you may as well just use `PostMessage()` and not any worker threads at all. Not to mention that you are also leaking every thread you create, you are not freeing any of them.

Comment: The idea is to query the database in the worker thread and then use the query data to populate the labels and list views in the methods which sync with the main thread. This example just shows the calls to the UI methods which provide the lists and labels with dummy data.  I will be sure to include an overloaded constructor which sets freeonterminate to true.

Comment: I already had the constructor in the production code but I was not checking the terminated property  in the execution method, this might be the problem.

Comment: Tried this in the production code, did not seem to make a difference. I added to the code example above.

Comment: I updated the code above to be a minimal example of exactly what my code is doing and also edited the question. Hopefully this will make it clearer what I am trying to do and what my problem is.

Comment: @Richard that is a bit better, although there are quite a few errors on it. `sender := nil` is useless, I think you meant `RefreshThread := nil` instead. `Timer1.Create(nil);` is just plain wrong, should be `Timer1 := TTimer.Create(Self); ` instead. Or drop a `TTimer` on the Form at design-time and not call `Create()` manually at all. And your thread `Execute()` is not well-protected from errors, and is leaking the `Query` object.

Comment: @Richard `Query.Create(nil);` is also wrong, use `Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);` instead, and then `Query.Free;` before the thread terminates. More importantly, `TADOQuery` uses ADO, an API based on apartment-threaded COM objects, so it cannot be accessed across thread boundaries without marshaling the ADO COM interfaces, which you are not doing. Do not use `Query` directly in your synced methods at all. Have `Execute()` copy the desired DB values to variables you declare in the thread class, and then the synced methods can use those variables instead.

Comment: I took out the use of the Query in the synchronized methods along with making the other suggested changes and the controls are now populated without having to shake the mouse. I also created collection objects to store all the records in for future use instead of calling the synchronize method for each iteration through the query results which sped things up a lot. Thanks a lot for your help Remy.