# How can I force my window to keep itself updated?

Tags: c++builder

## Final Update

The solution was to create a `TTimer`, set its `Interval` to any value greater than `0`, and assign its `OnTimer` property to an empty function.

---

I have a `TThread` that adds new controls to the main form at regular intervals, via `Queue()`.  But the queued functions are never executed until the form receives user input, or the cursor moves over it, and then it executes all the queued functions at once.

With careful logging I have determined conclusively that the functions are being queued as intended by the thread.  They simply aren't being executed by the main VCL loop until the form gets user interaction.

It's as if the main application loop doesn't run when there is no user interaction.

How can I force the form to execute queued functions immediately?

If it matters, the form and `TThread` are created by a `.dll`, which is called by another `.dll`, which itself is called by a console application.

Like this:

`console application -> dll -> dll created by C++ Builder`

## Edit

```cpp
void __fastcall GirkovArpa::Execute() {
    while (!Terminated) {
        if (GlobalMessageQueue.size() > 0) {
            EnterCriticalSection(&myCritSect);
            std::cout << "";  // this line is required, else thread won't execute
            std::string GlobalMessage = GlobalMessageQueue.at(0);
            std::string copy;
            copy.assign(GlobalMessage);
            GlobalMessageQueue.erase(GlobalMessageQueue.begin());
            LeaveCriticalSection(&myCritSect);
            Queue([&, copy]() {
                // do stuff
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit 2

`Node.JS console app` => `Node DLL addon` => `C++Builder GUI DLL`

My console application is specifically NodeJS.  It loads a "NodeJS addon" (a type of DLL), which loads the DLL created with C++ Builder, which exports this function:

```cpp
void myExportedFunction(const char *str) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&myCritSect);
    GlobalMessageQueue.push_back(std::string(str));
    // CheckSynchronize();
    LeaveCriticalSection(&myCritSect);
}
```

If `CheckSynchronize()` is not commented out, I get a `Segmentation Fault` error.

My `TThread` runs on an infinite loop, checking `GlobalMessageQueue`, and if it finds it's not empty, it queues a lambda which creates a `TControl` on the main form.

But the queued lambdas are not executed until the user interacts with the window (simply moving the cursor over the window will suffice).

## Edit 3

Here is my full lambda:

```cpp
Queue([&, copy]() {
                std::vector<std::string> words;
                boost::split(words, copy, boost::is_any_of(" "));

                // CREATE $TControl $Name $Text $Parent
                if (words.at(0) == "CREATE") {
                    if (words.at(1) == "TEXTBOX") {
                        String formName = stringToString(words.at(4));
                        TForm *form = getFormByName(formName);
                        TEdit *textbox = new TEdit(form);
                        textbox->Parent = form;
                        textbox->Name = words.at(2).c_str();
                        textbox->Text = words.at(3).c_str();
                        textbox->Show();
                        textbox->OnClick = MyForm->OnClick;
                    }
                    if (words.at(1) == "RADIO") {
                        String formName = stringToString(words.at(4));
                        TForm *form = getFormByName(formName);
                        TRadioButton *radio = new TRadioButton(form);
                        radio->Parent = form;
                        radio->Name = words.at(2).c_str();
                        radio->Caption = words.at(3).c_str();
                        radio->Show();
                        radio->OnClick = MyForm->OnClick;
                    }
                    if (words.at(1) == "BUTTON") {
                        String formName = stringToString(words.at(4));
                        TForm *form = getFormByName(formName);
                        TButton *button = new TButton(form);
                        button->Parent = form;
                        button->Name = words.at(2).c_str();
                        button->Caption = words.at(3).c_str();
                        button->Show();
                        button->OnClick = MyForm->OnClick;
                    }
                    if (words.at(1) == "FORM") {
                        createDialog(words.at(2).c_str(), words.at(3).c_str());
                    }
                }

                if (words.at(0) == "CHANGE") {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Screen->FormCount; j++) {
                        TForm *form = Screen->Forms[j];
                        if (form->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                            TRttiContext ctx;
                            TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(form->ClassInfo());
                            TRttiProperty *prop = type->GetProperty(words.at(2).c_str());
                            TValue value;

                            if (prop->PropertyType->TypeKind == tkUString) {
                                value = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(words.at(3).c_str());
                            } else if (prop->PropertyType->TypeKind == tkInteger) {
                                value = TValue::From<Integer>(StrToInt(words.at(3).c_str()));
                            } else {
                                std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
                            }
                            prop->SetValue(form, value);
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < form->ControlCount; i++) {
                            TControl *control = form->Controls[i];
                            if (control->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                                TRttiContext ctx;
                                TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(control->ClassInfo());
                                TRttiProperty *prop = type->GetProperty(words.at(2).c_str());
                                TValue value;

                                if (prop->PropertyType->TypeKind == tkUString) {
                                    value = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(words.at(3).c_str());
                                } else if (prop->PropertyType->TypeKind == tkInteger) {
                                    value = TValue::From<Integer>(StrToInt(words.at(3).c_str()));
                                } else {
                                    std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
                                }
                                prop->SetValue(control, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // GET NAME PROP
                if (words.at(0) == "GET") {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Screen->FormCount; j++) {
                        TForm *form = Screen->Forms[j];
                        if (form->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                            TRttiContext ctx;
                            TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(form->ClassInfo());
                            TRttiProperty *prop = type->GetProperty(words.at(2).c_str());

                            TValue result = prop->GetValue(form);
                            if (result.Kind == tkUString) {
                                String leString = result.AsString();
                                std::wstring w(std::wstring(leString.t_str()));
                                std::string STR(w.begin(), w.end());
                                std::string output = words.at(1) + " " + words.at(2);
                                String o = output.c_str();
                                tellJavaScript(AnsiString(o + ": " + leString).c_str());
                            } else if (result.Kind == tkInteger) {
                                int result_int = result.AsInteger();
                                String result_String = IntToStr(result_int);
                                String name = words.at(1).c_str();
                                String prop = words.at(2).c_str();
                                tellJavaScript(AnsiString(name + " " + prop + ": " + result_String).c_str());
                            } else {
                                // assume boolean
                                String result_String = BoolToStr(result.AsBoolean());
                                String name = words.at(1).c_str();
                                String prop = words.at(2).c_str();
                                tellJavaScript(AnsiString(name + " " + prop + ": " + result_String).c_str());
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < form->ControlCount; i++) {
                            TControl *control = form->Controls[i];
                            if (control->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                                TRttiContext ctx;
                                TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(control->ClassInfo());
                                TRttiProperty *prop = type->GetProperty(words.at(2).c_str());

                                TValue result = prop->GetValue(control);
                                if (result.Kind == tkUString) {
                                    String leString = result.AsString();
                                    std::wstring w(std::wstring(leString.t_str()));
                                    std::string STR(w.begin(), w.end());
                                    std::string output = words.at(1) + " " + words.at(2);
                                    String o = output.c_str();
                                    tellJavaScript(AnsiString(o + ": " + leString).c_str());
                                } else if (result.Kind == tkInteger) {
                                    int result_int = result.AsInteger();
                                    String result_String = IntToStr(result_int);
                                    String name = words.at(1).c_str();
                                    String prop = words.at(2).c_str();
                                    tellJavaScript(AnsiString(name + " " + prop + ": " + result_String).c_str());
                                } else {
                                    // assume boolean
                                    String result_String = BoolToStr(result.AsBoolean());
                                    String name = words.at(1).c_str();
                                    String prop = words.at(2).c_str();
                                    tellJavaScript(AnsiString(name + " " + prop + ": " + result_String).c_str());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (words.at(0) == "DELETE") {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Screen->FormCount; j++) {
                        TForm *form = Screen->Forms[j];
                        if (form->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                            form->Close();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < form->ControlCount; i++) {
                            TControl *control = form->Controls[i];
                            if (control->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                                control->Free();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (words.at(0) == "EXECUTE") {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Screen->FormCount; j++) {
                        TForm *form = Screen->Forms[j];
                        if (form->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                            std::cout << "EXECUTE <<" << words.at(2) << ">>" << std::endl;

                            TRttiContext context;
                            TRttiType *rttiType = context.GetType(form->ClassType());
                            TRttiMethod *method = rttiType->GetMethod(words.at(2).c_str());

                            DynamicArray<TRttiParameter *> parameters = method->GetParameters();
                            TValue args[10];
                            if (parameters.Length) {
                                for (int y = parameters.Low; y <= parameters.High; y++) {
                                    String paramType = parameters[y]->ParamType->ToString();
                                    if (paramType == "UnicodeString") {
                                        args[y] = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(stringToString(words.at(y + 3)));
                                    } else if (paramType == "Integer") {
                                        args[y] = TValue::From<Integer>(StrToInt(stringToString(words.at(y + 3))));
                                    }
                                }
                                TValue value = method->Invoke(form, args, parameters.High);
                            } else {
                                TValue value = method->Invoke(form, NULL, -1);
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < form->ControlCount; i++) {
                            TControl *control = form->Controls[i];
                            if (control->Name == words.at(1).c_str()) {
                                std::cout << "EXECUTE <<" << words.at(2) << ">>" << std::endl;

                                TRttiContext context;
                                TRttiType *rttiType = context.GetType(control->ClassType());
                                TRttiMethod *method = rttiType->GetMethod(words.at(2).c_str());

                                DynamicArray<TRttiParameter *> parameters = method->GetParameters();
                                TValue args[10];
                                if (parameters.Length) {
                                    for (int y = parameters.Low; y <= parameters.High; y++) {
                                        String paramType = parameters[y]->ParamType->ToString();
                                        if (paramType == "UnicodeString") {
                                            args[y] = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(stringToString(words.at(y + 3)));
                                        } else if (paramType == "Integer") {
                                            args[y] = TValue::From<Integer>(StrToInt(stringToString(words.at(y + 3))));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    TValue value = method->Invoke(control, args, parameters.High);
                                } else {
                                    TValue value = method->Invoke(control, NULL, -1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding.  I'm talking about `TThread::Queue`, not `TQueue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's as if the main application loop doesn't run when there is no user interaction.

It doesn't, actually.  Well, more accurately, when there is no pending window messages at all.  Once the main thread's message queue is emptied, the VCL calls the Win32 [`WaitMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitmessage) function, which blocks the calling thread until a new message appears in the message queue.  Even traditional non-VCL message loops tend to block the calling thread when there are no messages to process.

> How can I force the form to execute queued functions immediately?

You can't *force* it.

> If it matters, the form and `TThread` are created by a `.dll`, which is called by another `.dll`, which itself is called by a console application.

It DOES matter, because `TThread::Queue()` and `TThread:::Synchronize()` DO NOT work well inside of a DLL.

`TThread::Queue()` and `TThread::Synchronize()` put their requests into an internal queue inside the RTL, set a signal to indicate the queue has pending requests, and then post a message to the `TApplication` window to "wake up" the main thread (in case the message loop is "sleeping" waiting for a new message to arrive).  That request queue is processed at the main thread's earliest convenience.

By default, a VCL message loop processes the `TThread` queue only when:

- the message loop enters an idle state, after all pending messages have been processed and the message queue becomes empty.
- the `TApplication` window receives the "wake up" message.

When the `TThread` queue is inside a DLL, and the DLL is not sharing the same RTL instance with the main EXE, then the main message loop in the EXE does not know about the `TThread` queue in the DLL, so it can't process the pending requests during idle times.  That just leaves the "wake up" message, which the DLL will post to its own `TApplication` instance, not to the main EXE's `TApplication`.  The main thread message loop will still dispatch window messages to a DLL's `TApplication` window.

To solve this, you will have to either:

- enable Runtime Packages in the DLL and main EXE, or even change the DLL to be a Package, so that they can share common instances of the RTL and VCL.  That does mean you will have to deploy the RTL and VCL `.bpl` files with your app, though.
- export a function from your DLL that calls the RTL's [`CheckSynchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) function, and then call that DLL function in your EXE code periodically, such as in a UI timer, or in the `TApplication.OnIdle` event, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `CheckSynchronize()`.  From there I ended up at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854528/method-called-on-thread-using-synchronize-does-not-return-without-moving-the-mou) question, where the issue is exactly the same as mine.  I believe it's because my C++ Builder `.dll` (which is responsible for the GUI) is loaded by a console application.  I am now trying to figure out how to assign the proper method to `WakeMainThread `, since I'm convinced that will solve my problem.

Comment: You said the DLL creates a `TForm`, which means it also must have a `TApplication` object. The `TApplication` constructor assigns `WakeMainThread` to post a `WM_NULL` message to itself. `CheckSynchronize()` is called in the `TApplication`'s `WM_NULL` handler.

Comment: I added what is hopefully enough code to illustrate what my thread is doing, I am hoping you can glance at it to see if you notice any obvious problem.

Comment: Thre thread code is fine. That is not the issue. You would also have to show the console app code, and the other DLL's code that is calling into your C++Builder DLL, in order to figure out why `CheckSynchronize()` is not being called often enough.

Comment: Ah, so I take it it's can't be because my application is a "console" application then.

Comment: You said your DLL creates a `TForm`, that means it must also have a `TApplication` object. The `TApplication` constructor assigns `WakeMainThread` to post a `WM_NULL` message to itself, and `TApplication` calls `CheckSynchronize()` in its `WM_NULL` handler.  As long as your DLL is loaded in a thread (in the console app, or in the other DLL) that runs a message loop that dispatches the `WM_NULL` message to the `TApplication` window, then `Queue()` *should* work.

Comment: I tried to follow your second suggestion by simply copying and pasting `CheckSynchronize();` into the exported function which is used to tell the C++Builder DLL `TThread` to queue messages for the VCL thread.  As you can see in my most recent edit, that simply causes a `Segmentation Fault.`

Comment: By the way, I have been coming across many of your answers, some from years ago, almost everytime I search for a solution to some C++Builder question.  They've been very helpful and spared me a lot of trouble posting questions here.  So thanks for sharing your knowledge publicly.

Comment: The segfault is likely due to your lambda accessing data that has already gone out of scope since `TThread::Queue()` is *asynchronous*. Or maybe because your use of `GlobalMessageQueue` is not thread-safe (you need a lock around it). But even if you call `CheckSynchronize()` and it didn't crash (debug to figure out why), you still have a race condition. Between the time you `push_back` a string into your queue, and the time you call `CheckSynchronize()`, there is no guarantee that your thread has had enough time to call `TThread::Queue()`, so `CheckSynchronize()` may not have anything to do.

Comment: You're right.  Using `std::cout` I confirmed the race condition (not that it was necessary to confirm you were right about that lol), and I have conclusively eliminated it using a `CRITICAL_SECTION`, as you can see in my updated post.  But `CheckSynchronize()` still causes a `Segmentation Fault`.  I am trying to learn how to debug a `.DLL`.  It occurs immediately the first time the code reaches `CheckSynchronize()`.

Comment: Also using the program `Process Hacker` I discovered there is a thread in the process at address `0x0` that is taking `0.0% CPU`, which spikes to about `3% CPU` while I'm hovering the cursor over the window (which forces the GUI to update).  As soon the mouse leaves the window and there is no interaction, this thread falls back to `0% CPU`.  Meanwhile there are 2 other threads each taking up `25% CPU`, which I presume is the main `DLL thread` and the `TThread`.  So I need to keep that other thread alive.

Comment: I just learned `CheckSynchronize()` must be called in the main thread.  That is why the segmentation fault error is occurring.

Comment: @GirkovArpa your critical section addresses the issue of accessing your `GlobalMessageGueue` safely across threads (I would have suggested `std::mutex`, though), but it doesn't fix the race condition on `CheckSynchronize()`. And it should have been obvious that `CheckSynchronize()` needed to be called in the main thread, otherwise how else did you expect your lambda to run in the main thread so it can manipulate the UI?

Comment: I tried `for (long long int i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) CheckSynchronize();` inside `__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner) : TForm(Owner) { ... }`, and that also gave `Segmentation Fault.`  So inspired by the docs, I made `OnIdle` point to a function that called `CheckSynchronize()`.  Using `std::cout` I confirmed it was being fired continuously as long as the window was being interacted with (e.g. cursor moving over it), but ceased to fire when there was no user input.  And `CheckSynchronize()` had no affect whatsoever there, but at least it didn't cause a `Segmentation Fault`.

Comment: "*I tried `for (long long int i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) CheckSynchronize();` inside `__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner) : TForm(Owner) { ... }`*" - WHY? What would possess you to do that? "*that also gave Segmentation Fault*" - then your lambda is doing something it should not be doing, but you never showed that code. "*ceased to fire when there was no user input*" - `OnIdle` is fired only when the main message queue *becomes* idle. So once it is fired, it won't be fired again until the message queue receives new messages and then goes idle again. Consider using a timer instead.

Comment: What possessed me to do that:  I am running out of ideas, I figured it wouldn't hurt to try.  I updated my post with the entire lambda.  But I am positive the lambda isn't the problem.  It's just `CheckSynchronize()` that segfaults before the lambda even gets queued.  And without `CheckSynchronize()` the lambda works fine, exactly as intended.  The problem isn't the lambda, it's that the lambda sits in the queue until the window receives user input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213886/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-girkovarpa).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the main loop of a typical Windows program does not run until there's some sort of input (usually user input, but there are other kinds as well).

I'm not familiar with the C++ Builder framework.

If you have control of code that makes the main loop, you can modify it to process additional sources of information, such as watching for another thread to signal a synchronization object.

Other options:

- Have the thread that's adding items to the queue post a custom message to the main thread's window (or just a thread message) whenever it does one of its regular updates.
- Set up a timer on the main thread.  It will periodically "wake up" the main loop, just as the user input would.